# React Conditional rendering Order

Tags: java, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a react component which shows a table. If data length is 0 or data itself is null, then i am showing Message saying "No data exists".

The issue i am facing is, briefly the message (No data exists) appears for few milliseconds and then the table appears.

Please find below my implementation.

```
{!isLoading && !isError && (
  <div>
    {!isDataExists && (
      <Message>
        No Data exists
      </Message>
    )}
    {isExists && (
      <Table />
    )}
  </div>
)}
```

Please be noted i am using react functional component.

Comment: Where is the data for the table coming from? from an `API`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `loading` variable, I'm assuming you are getting data from an external API. Therefore, your pattern should look something like this:

If the `No data exists` message is appearing briefly, it's because your `loading` state is turning to `false` before the data has been set. Watch out for your `setState` call orders, and if you are waiting for the data before turning `loading` to `false`.

Your `loading` initial state should be `true`.

**NOTE:** You should use `async-await` instead of the `.then()` on the `useEffect`. I just used it here because stackoverflow snippets are outdated and didn't allow me to use `async-await`.

```js
function getDataFromApi() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("TABLE DATA"),1000);
  });
}

function App() {

  const [tableData,setTableData] = React.useState(null);
  const [loading,setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getDataFromApi().then((data) => {
      setTableData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  },[]);

  return(
    loading ?
      <div>Data is loading...</div>
    : <div>{tableData}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```